# Querying IP21 Value in in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, database, odbc, aspen

I am used to using `Aspen SQLplus` in order to query an `IP.21` database. Using the program I am able to write a statement like

```
Select 
    Value
From
    Table_Name
```

and it will return me the most recent value. I am trying to connect this database to an excel doc to do some analysis. I am able to connect the data source through an `ODBC` connection in excel but when I run the same query excel gives me the error.

> Details: "ODBC: ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Invalid object name 'Table_Name'."

Am I using improper syntax for the excel sql?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no IP21 record called 'Table_Name'.
Try with a real record name, like:

```
select IP_VALUE from "ATCAI"
```

You can get all available record with this query:

```
select name from all_records
```